# SQLITE - Flatten a key-value table into columns

Tags: sqlite

How would I go from a table like

```
key | value
----+-------
a   | ~~~~
b   | ~~~~
c   | ~~~~
d   | ~~~~
```

to something like the below

```
a | b | c | d
--+---+---+---
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

using sqlite?

Or rather how would I convert a table with multiple rows into a table with columns named after the keys of the previous table?

Comment: Are you trying to do this using just SQL or using something else?

Comment: @Whymarrh With just sql. I'm trying to make it so that I can join that table with another.